# Min and Max in Uninitialized Array

Tags: c++, arrays

The task is to take the the amount of rain for 12 months and store them into an array. Then based on the data collected calculate the sum, average, min and max. I found the sum and average just fine. I do not know where I went wrong with my max and min values.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    //inititalizing variables 
    double rain[13];
    double sum = 0;
    double max = rain[0];
    double min = rain[0];
    int count = 0;
    //string highMonth, lowMonth;

    //inputing rain values for each month 
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" << i << ":";
        cin >> rain[13];
        sum = sum + rain[13];
    }

    //finding the max  
    for ( count = 1; count < 13; count++)
    {
        if (rain[count] > max)
        {
            max = rain[count];
        }
    }
    //finding the min 
    for (count = 1; count < 13; count++)
    {
        if (rain[count] < min)
        {
            min = rain[count]; 
        }
    }

    //printing results 
    cout << " The total rainfall for the year is" << sum<<endl; 
    cout << "The average rainfall is: " << sum / 12<<endl; 
    cout << "The month with the highest rainfall was " << max <<  endl;
    cout << "The month with the lowest rainfall was " << min << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should initialise max and min to rain [0] after you input the values, otherwise there can be any number in it

Comment: You are out of bounds of the array.  You are writing every value you read *behind* the end of the array.  Also I don't know which planet you are from but here a year has twelve months, not thirteen.

Comment: I guess you should change `rain[13]` in `rain[i]` to store at the correct location. Also you'd want to use `std::vector` in the future to simplify your life.

Comment: So you want to use `std::cin >> rain[i]; sum += rain[i];`

Comment: Priming your max and min with extrema via `std::numeric_limits<double>`, you don't need the `rain[]` array in this *at all*, which not-coincidentally, would eliminate nearly every other problem you're having.

Comment: Are you using `double rain[13]` and attempting to ignore `rain[0]` element so that you are able to index each month starting at a base index of 1?  If that is the case, don't reference `rain[0]` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `std::array` and range-based for loops in C++11.  This is way less error prone.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //storage variable
    std::array<double,12> rain;

    //inputing rain values for each month
    double sum = 0;
    unsigned i = 0;
    for (auto &p : rain)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" << ++i << ": ";
        std::cin >> p;
        sum += p;
    }

    //finding the max
    double max = rain[0];
    for (auto &p : rain)
    {
        if (p > max)
        {
            max = p;
        }
    }

    //finding the min
    double min = rain[0];
    for (auto &p : rain)
    {
        if (p < min)
        {
            min = p;
        }
    }

    //printing results 
    std::cout << "The total rainfall for the year is " << sum << "\n";
    std::cout << "The average rainfall is: " << sum / 12 << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "The month with the highest rainfall was " << max <<  "\n";
    std::cout << "The month with the lowest rainfall was " << min << "\n";
}
```

Or even better, just use the STL.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //storage variable
    std::array<double,12> rain;

    //inputing rain values for each month
    unsigned i = 0;
    for (auto &p : rain)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" << ++i << ": ";
        std::cin >> p;
    }

    //finding the min, max, average
    auto max = *std::max_element(std::begin(rain), std::end(rain));
    auto min = *std::min_element(std::begin(rain), std::end(rain));
    auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(rain), std::end(rain), double{0.0});

    //printing results 
    std::cout << "The total rainfall for the year is " << sum << "\n";
    std::cout << "The average rainfall is: " << sum / 12 << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "The month with the highest rainfall was " << max <<  "\n";
    std::cout << "The month with the lowest rainfall was " << min << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess the way my professor is showing me how to do this is not the best way. Not a surprise.... thank you once again!!!!!

Comment: Your professor is prolly teaching you out to code algorithms as a teaching exercise.  That will help you understand them, in terms of how they are coded, and their complexity (Big-Oh).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should review your loop to be `cin >> rain[i]` and not `rain[13]`.
And `min`/`max` should be initialized with existing values.

Your array is uninitialized, so you are pointing on useless values.

You can do something like :

```
double max = 0;
double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

Comment: I am able to find the max value now but now the minimum value is 0 everytime now. I don't under stand why?!?!?! for (count = 0; count < 12; count++)
 {
  if (rain[count] < min)
  {
   min = rain[count]; 

  }
 }

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense either.  Read the array from the input and *then* set `double max = rain[0]; double min = rain[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
double rain[13]; // uninitialized here
double sum = 0;
double max = rain[0]; // garbage
double min = rain[0]; // garbage
// ...
```

`rain[0]` points to garbage when `max` and `min` are initialized. You should declare and initialize `max` and `min` after reading meaningful data into `rain`.

Comment: I initialized max right before the finding max for loop is that what you are talking about. I also initialized min before the min loop.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
double max = rain[0];
double min = rain[0];
```

in a not initialized array is the same as putting some garbage values on the 
variables **max** and **min**, you have to init to other values, and the same for the array **rain**.

The next issue was this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #" << i << ":";
        cin >> rain[13];
        sum = sum + rain[13];
    }
```

You are tryingto write at index 13 in the array which is definitely out of your bounds..

```
cin >> rain[i];
```

Would be the right thing with "i" from 0 to 13 exclusive

on the other hand your loops for finding the max  and min are incomplete (you are looping 12 times ignoring the element at index 0)

```
for ( count = 1; count < 13; count++)
```

if your array has 13 elements you must do

```
for ( count = 0; count < 13; count++)
```

Comment: My array is only supposed to have 12 values in it. So would i make it say      for(count = 0; count < 12; count++) ? If so where would I make it say that?

Comment: @Cantum2 -- **all** of your for loops should run from 0 to 12.